# Use Conditions in Functions Events AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I am trying to use the condition under the function block of serverless for enabled property of scheduled event. this is what it looks like right now:

```yaml
service: service-name
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  environment:
    ENV VARIABLES HERE
  region: eu-west-3
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: ${env:AWS_API_LAMBDA_POST_NAME}
  httpApi:
    id: ${env:AWS_API_GATEWAY_DATA_ANALYSIS_API_ID} 
layers:
  SOME LAYER HERE
functions:
  daily_function:
    handler: some_handler
    timeout: 30
    layers:
      - LAYER HERE
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(1 minute)
          enabled: !If [ IsProd, true, false ]
package:
  patterns:
    - '!.git/**'
    - '!tests/**'
    - '!layers/**'
resources:
  Conditions:
    IsProd: !Equals  
      - ${sls:stage}
      - prod
```

is anything wrong with that? Cant, I use it with that?

because it throws the error:
`"functions.daily_function.events.0.schedule.enabled": must be boolean`